# Voltage divider homework

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

I need help with the following homework problem.

[image: Please Help]

What I have done so far ......

Data

Voltage Supplied= 50V
Load Voltage= 50/3 = 16.66V
R1=?
R2=?
RL=?
P(Load) = 1.0 mW
VR1=?
VR2=?
IR1=?
IR2=?
IRL=?

Solution

Finding RL

P=V^2/RL
RL= V^2/P
RL= (16.66)^2/1.0 mW
RL=277.5 kilo ohms

VL=VR2=16.66V

VR1=50V-16.66V=33.34V

IRL=VL/RL
IRL=16.66/277.5
IRL=0.0600mA

IR1,IR2,R1 And R2 ?

Comment: What have you done so far? In which step or concept did you get stuck?

Comment: i have tried using RL=V^2/P to find Resistance RL But I'm stuck in finding R1 And R2 :(

Comment: Edit your question and add all that to it. Did you find the value of \$R_L\$? And even if you didn't, show all the steps/solution attempts you have done.

Comment: I have edited the title to reflect the content of the question rather than "Help Please Help" which tells us nothing.

Comment: Let me ask you some leading questions to help your train of thought. What’s the voltage across R2 and Rl? Consequently, what’s the voltage across R1?

Comment: Voltage across R1 and R2 is not given :( but I guess Voltage across R2 and RL will be same as both these resistors are in parallel =16.66V

Comment: Ok, so you have the voltage across R2 and RL, and you have the total voltage across them all, which is 50V. What is the voltage across R1?

Comment: Well, thats the tricky part.   Will it be 50V-VR1(?)-VR2(16.66)-VRL(16.66)=0?

Comment: No. You have to reread the KVL, you are applying it incorrectly. Once you do that, edit the question with the new info.

Comment: This problem is under specified, there's a whole set of solutions starting from R1=555kohm R2=infinity down to (nearly) zero ohm. There should be some other untold constraint

Comment: Well, the way I read it "determine the values of R1 and R2 to meet the given _specification_" does not mean there is a unique solution. Any solution (or all of them)  meeting the specification will suffice. But the main problem the OP is having is applying circuit analysis concepts, KVL, KCL, Equivalent resistance...

Comment: I Seem to have found the solution to my question R1=370.4 kilo ohms and R2= 555.33 kilo ohms I applied KVL on loop 2 and then substituted VR2 And VRL in it and managed to find R2 after that I found IR2  which led me to IR1 And R1. Thank You @jDAQ for the KVL,KCL Tip

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have answered your question in the comment above.  It's easy enough to calculate the value for \$R_L\$ given the voltage and power:
$$R_L = V_L^2/P_L = 277.8 k\Omega$$
What may have been stumping you is that the problem has an extra degree of freedom; you can choose the value for either \$R_1\$ or \$R_2\$ and calculate the other.  Your answer above is correct, but a simpler solution can be had if you choose \$R_2 = R_L\$, then \$R_2|| R_L =R_L/2\$, and since \$V_L\$ is \$1/3\$ of the supplied voltage, the required value of \$R_1\$ is twice that parallel combination, so \$R_1=R_L\$ as well.